# Trying to find the best way to check NullPointerException with nested multiple Object - Java 8

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type

I am trying to find the best way to check null pointer exception with the situation that I have got stuck. Please support me.

This is the main Class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private Car car;

    private Address address;

}
```

This is Car class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Car {

    private String name;

    private Insurance insurance;

}
```

This is the Insurance class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Insurance {

    private String name;

}
```

This is the Address class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {

    private String street;

}
```

This is the Class to Display (demo):

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class InformationDto {

    private String personName;

    private String carName;

    private String insuranceName;

    private String streetName;

}
```

This is the way that I try to check null pointer exception:

```
InformationDto dto = new InformationDto();
Optional.ofNullable(PERSON_CAR_NULL).map(i -> {
            dto.setPersonName(i.getName());
            Optional.ofNullable(i.getAddress()).map(e -> {
                dto.setStreetName(e.getStreet());
                return null;
            });
            return i.getCar();
        }).map(i -> {
            dto.setCarName(i.getName());
            return i.getInsurance();
        }).map(i -> {
            dto.setInsuranceName(i.getName());
            return null;
        }).orElse(null);
```

Comment: what is the harm in setting the value within an `if(something is not null)` clause?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, A simple null check will make the code more readable.

```
Person person = new Person();
    InformationDto dto = new InformationDto();
    if (person != null) {
        dto.setPersonName(person.getName());
        if (person.getAddress() != null) {
            dto.setStreetName(person.getAddress().getStreet());
        }
        if (person.getCar() != null) {
            dto.setCarName(person.getCar().getName());
            if (person.getCar().getInsurance() != null) {
                dto.setInsuranceName(person.getCar().getInsurance().getName());
            }
        }
    }
```